# Huge wait time for the files hosted thru Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, pagespeed

I started to host images on my website thru Google Drive. Example:

```
<img src="https://2eb42fb47e75d2a97a1177d65db9741d4c31baba.googledrive.com/host/0B6nwkauU1oHEbWVPTnp6aGE4WTQ/web-hosting-reviews.png" width="326" height="63" title="Web Hosting Reviews | Press to go to the home page" alt="Web Hosting Reviews">
```

However, the page load time actually increased after this implementation.
It seems like it does not use Google CDN, at least gtmetrix.com says it.

As I understand there is also no way to leverage browser caching for those files served thru google drive, isn't it?

Can you please provide me with any ideas why this method is slowing down my website and how to overcome it? In other words, how to host static files thru google drive efficiently (faster than thru the basic hosting from the own server)? If it is possible.

Edited on Jan 7, 2015:

I recently called Google to find out what is going on with it.

They told me that no matter what plan you have, there is a limit of 200 visits per file.

They also told me that the paid plan does NOT affect the speed of downloading.

Comment: are you using free `15gb` plan or you bought a plan from google drive?

Comment: Just the basic 15gb. Do you want to mention that it would be better, if I purchased a plan from them? 

Why do you think the disk space limit would affect the speed?

Comment: I think there is some kind of speed restriction when compared with free and premium plan.my uploads were bit slow when i was using free 15 gb but now its pretty fast.